# winsock client send data to sever

Tags: winsock

Good day everyone.
am new to winsock and am trying to send the message "JUST DO IT" from the client to server but instead the server print "->" instead of the message sent by the client I do not know if the problem is of some coding before sending .

am using loop on server listen and it is bad i will change to thread and put delay later

Thx in advance

server code

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include"iostream"
#define MAXLINE 1000
int main()
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        printf("Server: Error at WSAStartup().\n");
    // Create a SOCKET for listening for incoming connection requests.
    SOCKET sockListen;
    sockListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Server: Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof (servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(13); /* daytime server */
    if (bind(sockListen, (SOCKADDR*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Server: bind() failed.\n");
        closesocket(sockListen);
        return 0;
    }
    // Listen for incoming connection requests on the created socket
    if (listen(sockListen, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Server: listen(): Error listening on socket.\n");
    printf("Server: I'm listening on socket, waiting for connection...\n");

    int bytesRecv;
    char recvbuff[MAXLINE];

    while (1)
    {
        SOCKET sockConn = accept(sockListen, NULL, NULL);
        recv(sockListen, recvbuff, MAXLINE, 0);
        printf("Server Day Time: %s \n", recvbuff);
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

client code

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include"iostream"
#define MAXLINE 1000
int main()
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
        printf("Client: Error at WSAStartup().\n");
    // Create a SOCKET to connect to Server.
    SOCKET sockClient;
    sockClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Client: Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    char servHost[16];
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof (servAddr));
    printf("Enter Host IP: ");
    scanf("%s", servHost);
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servHost);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(13); /* daytime server */
    // Connect to a server.
    if (connect(sockClient, (SOCKADDR*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Client: connect() - Failed to connect.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    // Read data from server and display
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    sprintf(buff, "%.24s\r\n", "Just Do IT");
    send(sockClient, buff, strlen(buff), 0);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is with this line:
    sprintf(buff, "%.24s\r\n", "Just Do IT");

I don't think .24s makes any sense as a format directive. I would try with just %s and see if that works. Other than that the code *looks* OK.

Comment: No it is not ... just tried and i got the sameresault, but thanks though

Answer (score 0):

well after little work this is a working code of the client send to server message " just do it " i think there was something wrong with the socket addresses on the server side so just replace this

```
recv(sockConn, buff, MAXLINE, 0);
```

instead of this

```
recv(sockListen, recvbuff, MAXLINE, 0);
```